# How to include button text and links as part of css

Tags: css, navigationbar

I'm redesigning my company's website and am trying to create a horizontal navigation bar with button links (which I've managed somewhat). The problem is that the exact same menu is supposed to appear on every page (of which there are 100+) and the button options may increase of decrease in the future.

My question is this: Is there a way to place the button text and associated links in the external css to make re-coding and future edits to all those pages simpler? I've searched and tried everything I could think of. The below code is still very much a work in progress, so any advice would be appreciated.

Relevant css:

```
/* BEGIN Menu Buttons*/

#menu {text-align:center;}

#menu ul {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;}

#menu ul li {
    float: left;
    width: 140px;
    height:50px;
    list-style-type:none;}

#menu li a {
    width: 130px;
    height:40px;
    padding:5px;
    display:block;
    color: #fff ;
    background-color: #000 ;
    font: Times New Roman;
    font-size:14pt;
    line-height:40px;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration: none ;
    border-right:1px solid #fff;
    border-left:1px solid #fff;
    border-top: 1px solid #fff; 
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;;}

#menu li a:hover {
    border-top: 3px solid #000;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #000;
    outline: 1px solid #fff;
    font-size:16pt;}

/* END Menu Buttons*/
```

Relevant HTML:

```
<header>
<div id="menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="buy.html">Buy</a></li>
        <li><a href="sell.html">Sell</a></li>
        <li><a href="maintenance.html">Maintenance</a></li>
        <li><a href="parts.html">Parts</a></li>
        <li><a href="information.html">Information</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Are you using any type of framework? .Net, PHP, Ruby, etc...

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, certainly not intentionally. I'm using an combination of Dreamweaver CS4 , Notepad, and Apache OpenOffice to write everything myself.

Comment: php is a server side language that you would have to be set up for in order to use it.. if you are "unaware" if you are using it, than the answer most likely is "no". It is widely available though and most likely your best solution... your host company may already be set up for it as well... try a "hello world" .php file on your server and see if you can see it. if you can, you are all set and ready to begin diving into learning .php!

Comment: I'd not want to do that in css, your talking actual text values like "four men and a duck walked into a bar", this not a good idea.  Why?  Because the css is for your formatting of your display and at the least violates MVC traditions in a big way.  If not, ignore my comment :)

Comment: My server can apparently handle php, Ruby, and CGI, but I personally haven't used any of them. I'm prepared to learn if need be to accomplish what I need to, but I'm trying to work this so that others in the office (with no code experience at all) can do simple edits if I'm not there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, the solution I would use is PHP

First of all you would need to save your page to .php for this to work (instead of .html)

Secondly, create a new file (menu.php) and paste in the MENU code above.

In every page that you have, you replace the menu HTML code with this:

```
<?php

include 'menu.php';

?>
```

(assuming you put the menu.php in the same folder as the rest of your pages)

Now, if the content of your menu expands, just edit menu.php and your menu is updated on all pages that have your menu.php file included.

Comment: btw. is there a coding playground that allows php, html and css? (all-in-one)

Comment: I tried that suggestion, but the menu doesn't appear at all. I've never worked with php before though, are there any tags I might be missing? The header image and background color I'm using appear correctly.

Comment: Make sure you test the files in a server envoirement. If you are testing them "offline" the menu will not show up. Did you rename your index.html to index.php as well? put the menu.php in the same folder as index.php

Comment: I created test pages for both in php format and uploaded them to the server. That did work. This'll be useful when swapping out the old pages too, since I can simply get rid of all the html pages. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Another solution for you, If you aren't using php and you need an html solution, you can always lean on the iframe.

```
<iframe id="iframe" src="xxx.html" width="500" height="180"></iframe>
```

but the problem with this is you woudl need to update the `width` on every page, should your menu become larger (wider) than this iframe accounts for.